# Getting the value of input elements in a div after removing it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a dynamically added input text field inside a div. If I want to delete the particular div, i should retrieve the values of input field and put it in a variable. Here's a sample snippet:

```
     $(document).ready(function() {
    var max_fields      = 8; 
    var wrapper         = $(".input_fields_wrap"); 
    var add_button      = $(".add_field_button"); 

      var x = 0;
      var y = 2; 
      var temp;
      var subtotal=0;
      var totalPayment = 0;
      var totalTax = 0;
$(add_button).click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var i;
    if(x < max_fields){ 
        x++;
        i=y-1;
        temp = i-1;
        $(wrapper).append('<div class="container append" id="append" style="margin-top:25px;margin-bottom:25px;margin-left:15px;border:1px solid;padding:15px;"><div class="form-group col-sm-4"><label for="inputdefault">Name of Passenger</label><input class="form-control input-lg class_name" id="passname[]" name="passname[]" type="text"></div><div class="form-group col-sm-4"><label for="inputlg">Date of Birth</label><input class="form-control input-lg"  id="dateofbirth[]" name="dateofbirth[]" type="date"></div><a href="#" class="remove_field"><b><i class="fa fa-close"></i>Remove</a></b></div>'
          );
        y++;  
    }

});
```

After adding a the div with multiple fields, i would like to remove it and the remove method should handle the retrieval of data and store it in a variable.

```
     $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ 
    e.preventDefault(); 

     $(this).parent('div').remove();
    x--;

    //This method shall get the value of the input fields from the removed div.
})
```

Comment: you must get all the info you want from the div before you remove it.. make sense?

Comment: How about using [clone](https://api.jquery.com/clone/). before remove, clone the object to a temporary value.

Comment: yes sir, before i remove it, i would like to store it inside a variable

Answer (score 0):

Well one thing to note is that you need to get the values before you remove the div. So you would need to get them all then remove it. Something like this:

```
$(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ 
    e.preventDefault();

    var input_values = {};

    $(this).parent('div').find('input').each(function(){
        var key = $(this).attr('name');
        var value = $(this).val();
        input_values[key] = value;
    });

    $(this).parent('div').remove();
    x--;
});
```

In theory all your input values should then be in the object called input_values

EDIT: Assuming your elements have the name attribute

Comment: sir, how about storing each data in a variable? how to do that?

Comment: @ry-el I am storing it in a variable: input_values

Comment: how about i would like to use only one data? and disregard the other?

Comment: @ry-el You can do with the data whatever you like, you already retrieved it

Comment: It returns an array of data but i would only like to get only a specific value of field, how is it?

Comment: If you want the value of lets say the name input field, you can access it like this: `var name = input_values['name'];`

Comment: for example in my given field.
var deletedDoB = input_values['dateofbirth']; console.log(deletedDoB);


It returns undefine, why is it?

Comment: Maybe we should chat on the chatrooms, looks like you are having trouble

Comment: what chatroom sir? sorry newbie in stackoverflow

Comment: I don't think you have enough rep to enter a chatroom yet, I might have to look for another one quickly

Comment: i cant enter the chatroom sir, the site was blocked in my pc.

Comment: Sir just this,

console.log(input_values[key]) returns an array of data sir. For example heres the array of data: John Smith 19 I only want to get the value of 19, how to store it in variable if the name of my input looks like this name="age[]" its an array type.

Comment: Then you would have to access the data inside the array too, for example var `age = input_values['age[]'][0];`

Comment: i will use loop?

Comment: If you have multiple fields with the same name yes

Comment: what would my loop look like? sorry sir newbie in js

Comment: I will add it into the answer

Comment: Now that I think of it, it won't work, you will need some more help. Just find a chatroom you can enter and give me a link so we can talk.

Comment: do you have an account in www.slack.com sir?

Comment: Yes I have an account on slack

Comment: stackoverflow-group.slack.com pls join or give me your email

Comment: I can't give you my email address here for obvious reasons. You will have to find something that is publicly available